# Wordpress hook to filter buttons

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on [this](http://fvquotes.com/) website. I am trying to filter the the two arrows shown above each image(previous and next) if its the front page. I have created the following hook for it,

```
function removal() {
return null;
}

if(is_front_page()){
    add_filter('prev', 'removal');
    add_filter('next', 'removal');
}
```

The problem is that the images are still getting displayed. Any ideas why?

Comment: What is "none" supposed to mean, do you mean `null`?

Comment: Ah, ok. Also, are you sure the hook's correct name is `prev`? Where do you have that info from? It seems a bit short, considering the name for the previous *post* link is `previous_post_link`

Comment: `prev` is the class in which the previous image lies.

Comment: Where do you have the information for this from - a Codex page, or a tutorial? Can you point to it?

Comment: I was reading http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter for the help

Comment: Okay, but where did you get the "prev" and "next" information from? I can't find it anywhere in the Codex.

Comment: Shouldn't tag be used there in the first argument? The tutorial calls it $tag

Comment: `$tag (string) (required) The name of the filter to hook the $function_to_add to.` it needs to be the name of a WordPress API function that can deal with filters. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to remove the previous and next images for just the front page.

Comment: I think you are completely on the wrong path trying to use the WP API for that. Why not just use CSS? `<style>.prev, .next { display: none }</style>`

Comment: I could have done that but these images are present on other pages too and they should not be removed from there. CSS will cause them to be removed from everywhere

Comment: I edited my answer to give a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Edit:** there is a more elegant way in the CSS style-sheet, taking advantage of the fact that WP gives the home page's body the `home` class:
>
> ```
> body.home .prev,
> body.home .next { display: none }
> ```
>
> this targets the "prev" and "next" buttons on the home page **only**.

**Old answer:** Output the CSS in your `if(is_front_page())` call.

In the page's `<head>` section, do

```
 <?

  if(is_front_page())
   echo "<style type='text/css'>.prev, .next { display: none }</style>";


  ?>
```